# Uso di "opera" invece di "opus" come termine musicale / Usage of "opera" instead of "opus" as a musical term

Tags: word-usage

Alcuni giorni fa, stavo ascoltando il programma [Domenica in concerto](https://www.raiplayradio.it/programmi/domenicainconcerto/) su Radio 3 della RAI, e mi sono accorta che si usava il vocabolo "opera" invece di "opus" per parlare del contenuto del programma del concerto. Per esempio, si diceva qualcosa come "Sinfonia n. 3 in mi bemolle maggiore ***opera*** 55 di Beethoven"
(adesso non ricordo esattamente cos'era in programma) invece di "Sinfonia n. 3 in mi bemolle maggiore opus 55 di Beethoven".

La mia domanda sarebbe: è usuale questo uso del termine "opera" nell'ambito musicale? Non l'avevo mai sentito e non ho saputo trovare niente a riguardo.

---

## English version

<sup>(Improvements to this translation are welcomed)</sup>

Some days ago, I was listening to the program [Domenica in concerto](https://www.raiplayradio.it/programmi/domenicainconcerto/) on RAI Radio 3 and I realized that the word "opera" was used instead of "opus" to talk about the content of the concert program.  For instance, it was said something like "Sinfonia n. 3 in mi bemolle maggiore ***opera*** 55 di Beethoven" (I can't remember exactly what was on program) instead of "Sinfonia n. 3 in mi bemolle maggiore opus 55 di Beethoven" (that is, Beethoven's Symphony No. 3 in E-Flat Major, Op. 55).

Here is my question: is this usage  of the term "opera" usual in the field of music?  I had never heard of it and couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Ho sempre sentito dire “opera”; *opus* è termine ricercato.

Comment: @egreg: Nella [Wikipedia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(musica)), per esempio, si parla di "opus" e non si menziona che questo si dica anche "opera". E non ho trovato questa accezione di "opera" nei dizionari che ho consultato.

Comment: @Charo: "stavo ascoltando" :-)

Comment: Anche io ho sempre sentito usare "opera". SI usa invece "opus" in archeologia per dire il tipo di struttura muraria usata dai romani (qui, numero 2: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/opus/).

Comment: Grazie, @Benedetta, faccio la correzione. Infatti, ho avuto il dubbio su quale forma verbale usare quando ho scritto questa frase.

Comment: In italiano è la norma, in questo senso musicale che dici, parlare di “opera” (la sonata 27, opera 90, di Beethoven), anche se in genere per iscritto, nella denominazione di un brano, è abbreviato “op.” e per questo forse è meno facile trovare una fonte. Qualche esempio si trova magari cercando “numero d'opera” insieme a "sonata" etc.

Comment: @DaG: adesso mi sono accorta che nella [voce "opus" del dizionario dei  sinonimi e contrari Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/opus_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) appare "opera" come sinonimo del termine musicale "opus". Non l'avevo visto in altri dizionari però.

Comment: @Charo: prego! Il tempo continuo, in italiano, si fa sempre con il verbo "stare" (coniugato) + il gerundio. Al passato, si usa sempre l'imperfetto e non il passato prossimo di "stare".

Comment: *Opus* è semplicemente la versione latina di *opera*, che è ancora usato in ambiti tecnici (principalemente perché i cataloghi di opere usano quel termine) ma è effettivamente indistinguibile dal suo discendente in italiano.

Comment: @Gio: questo lo so, conosco già da tempo il significato di "opus" nell'ambito musicale. Il mio dubbio era che non avevo mai sentito usare il termine "opera" invece di "opus" con questo significato. E quando si cerca "opera" (non "opus") nei dizionari, in genere non appare questa accezione.

Comment: @Gio: Il dubbio non è sul significato, è sull'uso di "opera" con questo significato. A quanto ho potuto vedere dai commenti, "opera" si usa molto di più di "opus": è semplicemente questo quello che volevo sapere. Adesso qualcuno dovrebbe scriverlo a modo di risposta.

Comment: Completamente d'accordo, @Gio. Questa è la ragione per cui io avevo sempre immaginato che "op." si pronunciasse "opus" quando leggevo un testo di musica, il programma di un concerto, ecc in italiano. Ma il fatto reale è che, in Italia, molte volte si pronuncia "opera" (perlomeno in Radio 3 posso assicurarti che era così) e non "opus".

Comment: [Meta thread mentioning this question](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/same-question-but-in-english?), for reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In italiano, nel senso specifico di “elemento di un catalogo di opere musicali”, sono in uso sia “opera” che “opus”, ma il primo è di gran lunga molto più usato nella pratica dei musicologi, dei programmi di concerto, dei frequentatori delle sale.

A scanso dei giusti timori di chi considera questa una domanda troppo tecnica:

- una semplice ricerca con Google di “numero d'opera” (per escludere altri sensi di “opera”) confrontata con “numero d'opus” porta nel primo caso a decine di migliaia di risultati pertinenti in italiano, e nel secondo a molti risultati in francese, altri tradotti automaticamente o comunque dubbi e a pochissimi chiaramente pertinenti, ma siamo tutti d'accordo che un generico conteggio con Google vale poco;
- nella biografia che Piero Rattalino, grande musicologo, dedica a Chopin, troviamo varie volte l'espressione [“numero d'opera”](https://books.google.it/books?id=nUq7-QgYDLEC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22numero+d%27opera%22&source=bl&ots=Xg4Qa06JqS&sig=NDzaqEZw59kUtwDq4llJjvs8NMA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22numero%20d%27opera%22&f=false) e mai “numero d'opus”;
- idem per la [biografia di Šostakovič](https://books.google.it/books?id=2vim5XnmcDUC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=%22numero+d%27opera%22&source=bl&ots=ir59yGPf0Y&sig=WXYZf0yWAoUhM23w-nRJ9RXQOcA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22numero%20d%27opera%22&f=false) di Franco Pulcini e in molti altri testi su Google Books, fra cui altre biografie di compositori, partiture, cataloghi etc.;
- altra possibile ricerca che dà molti risultati significativi (su Google Books, che fa un poco più testo): [“le sonate dell'opera”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22le+sonate+dell%27opera%22&oq=%22le+sonate+dell%27opera%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22le+sonate+dell%27opera%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&*), che è un tipico modo in cui un musicologo parla di un gruppo di sonate che compongono appunto un'unica opera (o, più formalmente, che condividono uno stesso numero d'opera) nel catalogo di un compositore (un'analoga disparità di risultati ovviamente si ottiene anche con “quartetti dell'opera” e così via);
- questo non lo posso portare esplicitamente, ma basta sintonizzare una radio o andare sul sito della Rai: sia [Radio 5 Classica](http://www.radiofd5.rai.it/dl/portali/site/articolo/ContentItem-b9b6ddfd-9dd2-459d-93bc-f06c9c182e53.html) (già Quinto canale della filodiffusione) – che trasmette solo musica classica – che [Rai Radio 3](http://www.radio3.rai.it/dl/portaleRadio/Page-a92d14c3-2fa3-4df6-8b7d-f1c15eefdc0d.html#slider-1-1) – che le offre un discreto spazio – presentano i brani sciogliendo sempre (a quel che posso ricordare) “op.” in “opera”;
- infine, alla voce [“op.”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/op/) il vocabolario Treccani offre:

> Abbreviazione del lat. *opus* (v.), nella designazione delle composizioni musicali di un autore secondo un numero d’ordine progressivo. In contesti italiani s’intende e si legge comunemente come abbreviazione di *opera*.

- e ancor più esplicitamente lo Zingarelli, accessibile solo a pagamento, dà per “Op.”:

> 1 Opera (in bibliografia)
> 2 (*mus.*) Opera (con riferimento al catalogo delle composizioni)

---

**English version of the answer**

In Italian, in the specific sense of “element of a catalogue of musical works”, both *opera* and *opus* are in use, but the former is far more used in the practice of musical scholars, programmes, concert habituées. (This use of *opera* is not to be confused with the genre of dramatic works with music and singing.)

Some remarks and sources:

- a simple Google search for “numero d'opera” (to exclude other meanings of *opera*) compared with “numero d'opus” returns for the former tens of thousands of relevant results in Italian, and for the latter many results in French, other ones translated automatically into Italian, mostly doubtful and very few clearly relevant, but we all agree that a generic count with Google is worth little;
- in the biography of Chopin by Piero Rattalino, the great Italian music scholar,, we find several times the phrase [“numero d'opera”](https://books.google.it/books?id=nUq7-QgYDLEC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22numero+d%27opera%22&source=bl&ots=Xg4Qa06JqS&sig=NDzaqEZw59kUtwDq4llJjvs8NMA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22numero%20d%27opera%22&f=false) and never “numero d'opus”;
- ditto for the [biography of Šostakovič](https://books.google.it/books?id=2vim5XnmcDUC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=%22numero+d%27opera%22&source=bl&ots=ir59yGPf0Y&sig=WXYZf0yWAoUhM23w-nRJ9RXQOcA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22numero%20d%27opera%22&f=false) by Franco Pulcini and in many other texts on Google Books, including other biographies of composers, scores, catalogues and so on;
- another possible search giving many significant results (on Google Books, slightly more reliable): [“le sonate dell'opera”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22le+sonate+dell%27opera%22&oq=%22le+sonate+dell%27opera%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22le+sonate+dell%27opera%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&*), which is a typical way in which a scholar talks about a group of sonatas that make up a single opus (or, more formally, sharing the same opus number) in the catalogue of a composer (as expected, we get a similar difference in results with “quartetti dell'opera” and so on);
- I cannot cite this explicitly, but just tune in a radio or go to the Rai website: both [Radio 5 Classica](http://www.radiofd5.rai.it/dl/portali/site/articolo/ContentItem-b9b6ddfd-9dd2-459d-93bc-f06c9c182e53.html) - which broadcasts just classical music - and [Rai Radio 3](http://www.radio3.rai.it/dl/portaleRadio/Page-a92d14c3-2fa3-4df6-8b7d-f1c15eefdc0d.html#slider-1-1) - which often airs it - always introduce musical pieces reading “op.” as “opera”;
- finally, in the article [“op.”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/op/) of the Treccani dictionary, we find: "Abbreviation of Latin *opus*, in the designation of the musical compositions of an author according to a progressive order number. In Italian contexts it is commonly understood and read as an abbreviation for ‘opera’”. Even more explicitly the Zingarelli (behind a paywall), gives for “Op.”:
  1 Opera (in a bibliography)
  2 (*music*) Opera (with reference to a catalogue of compositions)

Comment: Grazie mille, @DaG! Non mi era passato per la testa che ci fosse la voce "op." nel Treccani!

Answer (score 2):

Immagino che uno straniero trovi insolita questa parola perché pensa all'opera lirica, ma qui questa parola viene usata nel suo senso di "55esimo lavoro prodotto da Beethoven" e non ha nulla a che vedere con teatri, tenori e scenografie.

Probabilmente c'è una sfumatura di significato che è *lost in translation* qui: quando un italiano legge *opera 55*, il senso a cui pensa è quello di *frutto, risultato di un lavoro intellettuale, nel campo delle lettere, delle scienze e delle varie arti*, cioè l'inglese *work*. Quando un non-italiano legge *opera 55*, il senso a cui pensa è *rappresentazione scenica di un testo drammatico (libretto) in cui i personaggi si esprimono per mezzo del canto e con accompagnamento orchestrale*, cioè l'inglese *opera*. (Entrambe le definizioni dal Treccani.)

---

The Italian word *opera* is a literal translation of the Latin *opus*, and means *work*, as in anything that is the result of work, in particular that of an artist. I can imagine that foreigners associate that word mainly with the English *opera* (theatrical representation in which the actors sing accompained by an orchestra), and that it may sound weird in this context; however, in this context this is a false friend. *Opera 55* simply means that it is the 55th musical piece produced by Beethoven according to some catalogue, without any references to theaters, stages, tenors and sopranos.

Comment: You got it exactly right. I saw "opera" on some mandolin music because I thought *opera* meant the same thing in both languages. I was accustomed to seeing "op." or "opus" in my orchestra scores, so I got confused. To my knowledge, Calace didn't write any theatrical works, so I thought I was missing out on something big!